# Error when referencing TextMeshPro in Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm switching from Text(legacy) to TextMeshPro in Unity. When switching I've tried using

```
public TextMeshProUGUI ScoreText;
```

but get this error: Assets\scrips\gamemanager.cs(17,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class gamemanager : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public TextMeshProUGUI ScoreText; 
    int scoreText = 0;
    string ScoreText_string;

    
    
    
    public void NextLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    public void plusTen()
    {
        scoreText += 10;
    }
    
    

    void Update() 
    {
        ScoreText_string = scoreText.ToString(); 
        ScoreText.text = ScoreText_string;


    }




}
```

Note: editor version 2021.3.1f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextMeshProUGUI` class resides in `TMPro` namespace. You must have to use the namespace `TMPro` with `using` statement or simply do

```
public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI ScoreText;
```

Also, you must have to import the `TextMeshPro` package in your project as well.